# Rancher RKE2 Cert-manager's Vault issuer says "permission denied"

Tags: kubernetes, vault, rancher, cert-manager, rke2

Does anyone know what's wrong with Rancher RKE2 clusters, please? I've hit strange problems during the deployment of Cert-manager with Vault issuer where Vault gets "permission denied" (or more exactly `kubectl describe clusterissuers vault-issuer` shows `Error initializing issuer: while requesting a Vault token using the Kubernetes auth: error calling Vault server: Error making API request.; URL: POST https://vault.services.xxx.net/v1/auth/kubernetes/login Code: 403. Errors: * permission denied`) even though it runs fine in the Rancher's local cluster (it's RKE1 deployed with "rke up" on 3 nodes).

Without going into much detail about this that would make it rather too complicated, I'd prefer to focus on some clues that are IMO related...

1. Despite of having correct RBAC rules installed Kubernetes denies "kubectl auth can-i" tests, like this one:

» kubectl auth can-i create tokenreviews --as=system:serviceaccount:default:vault-issuer
Error from server (Forbidden): {"Code":{"Code":"Forbidden","Status":403},"Message":"clusters.management.cattle.io "c-m-4jbln242" is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:vault-issuer" cannot get resource "clusters" in API group "management.cattle.io" at the cluster scope","Cause":null,"FieldName":""} (post selfsubjectaccessreviews.authorization.k8s.io)

even when I allow listing clusters like this:

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: cattle-mgmt-get-clusters
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: list-clusters
  # no luck even if referencing cluster-admin clusterrole 
  #kind: ClusterRole
  #name: cluster-admin
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    name: vault-issuer
    namespace: default
```

...it doesn't work.

2. I've found out that my vault-issuer SA allegedly doesn't exist (which is not true) when using raw command:

```
Error from server (NotFound): service accounts "vault-issuer" not found
# but sure, it exists when getting it in a normal way...
» kubectl get sa -n default vault-issuer
NAME           SECRETS   AGE
vault-issuer   0         6h31m
```

The vault-issuer SA was created like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: vault-issuer
  namespace: default
```

Rancher version: v2.7.9
RKE2 cluster version: v1.26.11+rke2r1

My cluster's configuration is very standard... CoreDNS, Calico, Nginx Ingress controller... here's its yaml configuration:

```
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: infra-cloud
  annotations:
    field.cattle.io/creatorId: user-7ts7q
    field.cattle.io/description: Common Infra Cloud
  creationTimestamp: '2024-01-05T12:48:38Z'
  finalizers:
    - wrangler.cattle.io/provisioning-cluster-remove
    - wrangler.cattle.io/rke-cluster-remove
    - wrangler.cattle.io/cloud-config-secret-remover
  generation: 2
  labels:
    {}
  namespace: fleet-default
  resourceVersion: '84718360'
  uid: c8f76d68-9bc7-4608-81fa-81fe06c960ca
  fields:
    - infra-cloud
    - 'true'
    - infra-cloud-kubeconfig
spec:
  clusterAgentDeploymentCustomization:
    appendTolerations:
    overrideAffinity:
    overrideResourceRequirements:
  defaultPodSecurityAdmissionConfigurationTemplateName: ''
  defaultPodSecurityPolicyTemplateName: ''
  fleetAgentDeploymentCustomization:
    appendTolerations:
    overrideAffinity:
    overrideResourceRequirements:
  kubernetesVersion: v1.26.11+rke2r1
  localClusterAuthEndpoint:
    caCerts: ''
    enabled: false
    fqdn: ''
  rkeConfig:
    chartValues:
      rke2-calico: {}
    etcd:
      disableSnapshots: false
      snapshotRetention: 5
      snapshotScheduleCron: 0 */5 * * *
    machineGlobalConfig:
      cni: calico
      disable-kube-proxy: false
      etcd-expose-metrics: false
    machinePoolDefaults:
    machinePools:
    machineSelectorConfig:
      - config:
          protect-kernel-defaults: false
    registries:
      configs:
        {}
      mirrors:
        {}
    upgradeStrategy:
      controlPlaneConcurrency: '1'
      controlPlaneDrainOptions:
        deleteEmptyDirData: true
        disableEviction: false
        enabled: false
        force: false
        gracePeriod: -1
        ignoreDaemonSets: true
        skipWaitForDeleteTimeoutSeconds: 0
        timeout: 120
      workerConcurrency: '1'
      workerDrainOptions:
        deleteEmptyDirData: true
        disableEviction: false
        enabled: false
        force: false
        gracePeriod: -1
        ignoreDaemonSets: true
        skipWaitForDeleteTimeoutSeconds: 0
        timeout: 120
  machineSelectorConfig:
    - config: {}
__clone: true
```

Also when I try (1) and (2) in my other (and an older) RKE2 cluster (that was created by a different Rancher) it behaves the same. When I test it on a local KIND cluster, it works as expected.

What am I missing? Some RBAC, or it's any Rancher's hardening (I'm not using CIS Profile, btw). Thank you in advance!

UPDATE: I've found that I can enable Authorized Cluster Endpoint under Rancher cluster's configuration (Rancher UI: config -> Networking -> Authorized Endpoint), then raw commands work as expected, also testing with `vault write auth/kubernetes/login role=vault-issuer jwt="<your_token>"` now doesn't return "permission denied", so there it looks like the culprint is Rancher's authentication proxy and it's impersonalisation feature. But cert-manager's vault-issuer still returns "permission denied" for some reason. Unfortunatelly for me using ACE isn't a good solution so I don't plan to go any deeper, but it can be something else like some wrong params in JWT token... Anyway, anyone else have an idea if it's possible to solve this using the Rancher endpoint (auth proxy)?

UPDATE2: so basically this one is a known issue: https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/22417 (the overall one & Open) + https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/16221 + https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/17447 + https://github.com/rancher/rancher/issues/14997

It's unhappy... ACE is not good for us, so we will keep finding another solution or we will temporarily use AppRole auth.